# Migrated Bootcamp Partition using WinClone, Damaged MBR

Tags: macos, windows-8, mac, macbook, boot-camp

Dual-OS Scenario:

- Partition 0 runs OS X Mavericks - 250 GBs
- Prtition 1 runs Windows 8.1 - 250 GBs, installed using bootcamp

I recently bought a new mac and wanted to migrate everything, so I used Time Machine to migrate all my OSX settings and Winclone to copy the entire windows partition unto an image.

I opened the new PC, chose restore from existing Time Machine and in about an hour had my machine exactly setup as the last one. Everything OK there.

Then I proceeded to restore using Winclone, the app asked to update the MBR with a generic one in order to be able to boot correctly, I said yes, and everything's ok.

Now, whenever I boot up using windows, everything runs fine. If I boot up using OS X, the system gets extremely slow (around 3-4 minutes to log in). After that everything works fine, it's just very weird that it takes so long to actually startup OS X.

Any ideas on why this may be happening or how to fix it? I'm thinking about just formatting the entire drive and starting from scratch.

Comment: Have you tried booting OS X with `shift` pressed, and then rebooting? It will then rebuild some caches.

Comment: This doesn't sound like it has anything to do with the MBR. As soon as it *starts* booting into osx or windows, the MBRs work is pretty much done unless it reads the partition table again... And if any of that fails its a quick and obvious failure, not like what you describe.

Comment: I deleted the windows partition and rebooted. 
The weird thing is that if I boot with the alt key down to show all available boot options, the Windows Hard Drive is still there, that's why I thought about the MBR or partition table being configured wrong.

Comment: Before restoring the Windows partition from Winclone I had experienced no trouble booting up

Comment: YESSS doing the Shift-thing worked great!

Answer (score 2):

To shed some light on the presence of a Windows selection at Option-startup, Winclone restored the Windows 8.1 image to the new Mac in EFI mode, which writes the boot data to disk0s1, the EFI partition.  Deleting a Boot Camp partition in Disk Utility will not remove the boot information from the EFI partition.  In cases where Windows will not be restored or reinstalled, you may mount the EFI partition and remove the /EFI/Boot and /EFI/Microsoft folders and Windows will no longer appear as a boot option at Option-startup.

Regards,

Russell Scheil,
Twocanoes Software, Inc.